# Facebook linter returns “Error parsing input URL” although most info shows up if FB button is activated

Tags: facebook

I’m trying to troubleshoot a specific behavior. The last entry I wrote on a WordPress blog returns no data when run through Facebook’s Object Debugger (linter). I just get a “Error Parsing URL:Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.”

- However, if I try with any previous post, all seems to be fine: the linter scrape the page correctly;
- If the Facebook button under the problematic entry is clicked, a snippet is correctly produced, except for a thumbnail of the image: permalink, summary, all is correct.
- When I examined the source code of for the permalink entry in my browser, I can see all tags correctly displayed, even the `og:image` tag (the URL is valid).

This is sudden behavior. I didn’t experience any problem since I setup Facebook Open Graph protocol on my blog.

P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Sometime between the time I created my previous entry and the time I wrote the new one, the CDN (content delivery network) I’m running me blog through stopped working.

Facebook linter wasn’t happy because it couldn’t find the image (since the image wasn’t distributed through the CDN: the CDN handles media, not plain text, that’s why Facebook was still able to scrape title, summary, etc.).

Lesson learned: when running test with Facebook Object Debugger, first disable any cache system (or make sure it works properly) or it may impact the results.